# How do I compare two lines (if they are equal or not equal) of a file read inside a while loop?

Tags: perl

I have a file like this one below, where the line starting with a number is an ID for my sample and the following lines are the data.

```
10001;02/07/98;;PI;M^12/12/59^F^^SP^09/12/55
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D16S539
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D7S820
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D13S317
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D5S818
10002;02/07/98;;RJ;F^20/04/86^SP^
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;10;12;11;;D10S212
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;8;8;10;8;;D7S820
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;11;14;11;;D13S317
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;13;12;13;8;;D5S818
```

For the lines containing the data, I would like to test whether or not the fields 6-11 are the same because I want the data only if they are **not equal** to each other (in the first case they are all '9').

So I thought about splitting the lines and store them as an array, and then compare the arrays with the ~~ operator. But how do I do that if I'm reading the file inside a while loop and the array is redefined each line? 
Or maybe there is better ways to do that.

Thanks in advance!

This is a pseudocode to illustrate what I want to do:

```
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /;/;
    if ($field[0] eq '') {
        if @fields[6 .. 11] is not equal to @fields[6 .. 11] in all the next lines {
            do my calculation;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if **all** of the lines are identical, or if **any** of the lines are identical?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if they are all identical.

Comment: With ikegami's answer, it seems as though you only want to compare the fields... when I asked, you wanted to compare the *lines*. Which is it?

Comment: @TLP, I want to compare the fields 6-11 across lines. For example, if @fields[6..11] is equal to @fields[6..11] in all the following lines for that sample, I don't want this data.

Comment: So in other words, you chose bad input for your example. If you had lines `1;2;3;4;5` and `1;2;3;4;5`, that would mean you consider them "equal". But `1;1;1;1;1` and `2;2;2;2;2` are fine. And if you have `1;2;3;4;5`, `1;2;3;4;5` and `2;2;2;2;2`, you would not consider them all equal, and would want them included.

Comment: @Vitor Aguiar, Regarding the question you posted and deleted, always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! Yes, I do have strict and warnings on. Even so, this time I can not figure out my mistake. I have 2 for loops with the same structure, one works fine, the other one doesn't work... I have an array with the order of keys in a hash and I want to iterate through it, using the value for that key. The one which works is "foreach my $id (@order) {print(",", $hash1{$id}};". The other is "foreach my $i (@order) {if($hash1{$i}==$hash2{$i}) {do calc}}. In this last one I get an error saying "my 'key name' is not a numeric value..." but I want the value for that key, not the key itself.

Comment: @Vitor Aguiar, The only way you could get that warning from that code is if the value of `$hash1{$i}` or `$hash2{$i}` is `key name`.

Comment: but $i is my key name and $hash{$key} extracts the value of my key, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I correct in saying that data really represents two records? If so, you want to accumulate the lines for for the full record.

```
my @super_rec;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /;/;
    if ($fields[0] ne '') {
       process_rec(\@super_rec) if @super_rec;
       @super_rec = \@fields;
    } else {
       push @super_rec, \@fields;
    }
}

process_rec(\@super_rec) if @super_rec;
```

Then, your question can be answered.

```
sub process_rec {
    my ($super_rec) = @_;
    my ($rec, @subrecs) = @$super_rec;

    my $do_calc = 0;
    for my $i (1..$#subrecs) {
        if (  $subrecs[0][ 6] ne $subrecs[$i][ 6]
           || $subrecs[0][ 7] ne $subrecs[$i][ 7]
           || $subrecs[0][ 8] ne $subrecs[$i][ 8]
           || $subrecs[0][ 9] ne $subrecs[$i][ 9]
           || $subrecs[0][10] ne $subrecs[$i][10]
           || $subrecs[0][11] ne $subrecs[$i][11]
        ) {
           $do_calc = 1;
           last;
        }
    }

    if ($do_calc) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ikegami, thank you. This is really sophisticated and as I'm a beginner in Perl, I'm having some trouble to implement it in my real code. I should include my calculation in the part "if($do_calc) {}", but that doesn't work because this calculation involves looping through the file (the real file has thousands of records) and using the fields (@fields) in each line to do some computations. Since you already looped through the file in your initial while loop, I can't do it again. If I open the file again, and split the fields again, your subroutine seems to have no effect!

Comment: Of course this is because I don't understand quite well how subroutines work... I'm studying about that and I'll try it again. Thanks!

Comment: It calls the sub each time for each "super record" as it finishes reading it, not after the whole file is read. In your example data, there are two "super records".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking to compare data across lines, not within a single line. If I've got that wrong, ignore the rest of my answer.

The way I would do it is to re-join fields 6 through 11 as a string. Keep the data from the first line as $firstdata, and compare data from each successive line as $nextdata. Each time the data don't match, you up the $differences counter. When you get an ID line, check to see if the previous $differences was greater than zero and if so do your calculation (you may need to save the ID line and other fields in some other variables). Then re-initialize the $differences and $firstdata variable.

```
my $firstdata = "";
my $nextdata = "";
my $differences = 0;
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /;/;
    if ($field[0] eq '') {
        $nextdata = join(';', @fields[6..11]);
        if ($firstdata && ($nextdata ne $firstdata)) {
            $differences++;
        } else {
            $firstdata = $nextdata;
        }
    } else {
        if ($differences) {
            # do your calculation for previous ID
        }
        $firstdata = "";
        $differences = 0;
    }
}
if ($differences) {
    # do your calculation one last time for the last ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with `Regex`. This might be inefficient than other methods, if the indices are fixed from 6 to 11, and are known to be those only, because it will traverse entire String: -

```
open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    my $num = 0;
    my $same = 1;
    while (/;(\d+);/) {

       if ($num == 0) { $num = $1; } 
       elsif ($1 != $num) { $same = 0; last; }

       # Substitute current digit matched with x (or any char) 
       # to avoid infinite loop
       s/$1/x/; 
    }  

    if ($same) {
       print "All digits same";
    }
}
```

Comment: `true` and `false` are not perl concepts, and the `break` keyword is used for the `switch` feature, not loops. You might be thinking of `next` or `last`.

Comment: @TLP. Oh! Didn't knew that. Or forgot that actually. And what should I use in place of true or false? Because its working.

Comment: It's not working, though it may look like its working if you don't have warnings turned on. In perl, any value that is 0, undef a blank string or an empty list is false. Any other value is true.

Comment: @TLP. Ok, looks like that was the reason. When I added `use warnings`, I saw red mark pointed to those lines. I changed it, and it went away. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) module you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use feature 'say';

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
        sep_char    => ";",
        binary      => 1,
    });

my %data;
my @hdrs;  # store initial order of headers
my $hdr;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
    if ($row->[0] =~ /^\d+$/) {
        $csv->combine(@$row) or die "Cannot combine: " .
            $csv->error_diag();
        $hdr = $csv->string();   # recreate the header 
        push @hdrs, $hdr;        # save list of headers
    } else {
        push @{ $data{$hdr} }, [ @{$row}[6..11] ];
    }
}

for (@hdrs) {
    say "$_\n   arrays are: " . (is_identical($data{$_}) ? "same":"diff");
}

sub is_identical {
    my $last;
    for (@{$_[0]}) {         # argument is two-dimensional array
        $last //= $_;
        return 0 unless ( @$_ ~~ @$last );
    }
    return 1;                # default = all arrays were identical
}


__DATA__
10001;02/07/98;;PI;M^12/12/59^F^^SP^09/12/55
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D16S539
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D7S820
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D13S317
;;;;;M1|F1|SP1;9;9;9;9;9;9;;D5S818
10002;02/07/98;;RJ;F^20/04/86^SP^
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;10;12;11;;D10S212
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;8;8;10;8;;D7S820
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;12;11;14;11;;D13S317
;;;;;F1|SP1;;;13;12;13;8;;D5S818
```

**Output:**

```
10001;02/07/98;;PI;M^12/12/59^F^^SP^09/12/55
   arrays are: same
10002;02/07/98;;RJ;F^20/04/86^SP^
   arrays are: diff
```